# Is sencha touch / jquery mobile mature enough for production?

Tags: jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

Last week i've been busy with mobile html5 frameworks like sencha touch and jquery mobile.

I bumped into a few bugs and strange things when testing on real android phones. (from slow to missing components to even not displaying anything)

Is it correct to say that html5 frameworks for mobile platforms aren't ready for production when one of the requirements is that it must function on most android/iphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to support most android phones, you should be aware of that performance will not be satisfying on middle to low-end devices. This is because that both libraries depend heavily on javascript( especially sencha ), and javascript and the whole webkit performance are not great on these phones. The situation is a bit better on the iphones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jquery, but sencha touch sure is. 
See if the android bugs you found are mention here because they will or already are solved in the next release.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135798-List-of-Known-Android-Issues-Fixed-in-Upcoming-Release

The sencha touch 2 is going to have all other improvements especially, bugs and performance related to android OS. Read it here:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-what-to-expect

In the end test and see it yourself some of the apps that are built with sencha touch:

http://www.sencha.com/apps/